# Is it possible to get the sum while executing a join?

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

I have this code:

```
select id,
p1.value as company,
p2.value as budget

FROM  process p

LEFT JOIN Param p1 on p1.ID = p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Company'
LEFT JOIN Param p2 ON p2.ID = p.ID AND p2.NAME = 'Budget'

where type = 'Authorization';
```

I have few companies. Here a sample result is:

```
Company      Budget

Goodis       10000
McDonalds    15000
Goodis       500
Goodis       100
Everest      100
McDonalds    1000
Everest      10000
```

What I want to do is to get the sum of the budget per company(I can't seperate the companies in the where clause, because I need the whole data and there are tons of companies). It seems kinda hard for me to be done just in SQL. I'm trying to do a BIRT report, so, if you have any suggestions of getting it on BIRT level I will be also very happy!

Is it a way to do this, or my tries are pointless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want an analytic function:

```
select id, p1.value as company, p2.value as budget,
       sum(p2.value) over (partition by p1.value) as CompanyBudget
FROM  process p
LEFT JOIN Param p1 on p1.ID = p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Company'
LEFT JOIN Param p2 ON p2.ID = p.ID AND p2.NAME = 'Budget'
where type = 'Authorization';
```

This will return the total budget on each line, but not reduce the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY p1.value` with `SUM`:

```
select 
  p.value as company,
  COALESCE(SUM(p2.value), 0) as Totalbudget
FROM  Param AS p
LEFT JOIN process AS p1 ON p.ID = p1.ID AND p.NAME = 'Company'
LEFT JOIN process AS p2 ON p.ID = p2.ID AND p.NAME = 'Budget'
GROUP BY p.value;
```

Comment: I just got the same result as the mentioned in the post. :(

Comment: @Slim It should work fine. Can you please post some sample data from the two tables `param` and `process` it will be very helpful to explain this issue. Thanks

Comment: It's not working well and I will explain you why. :) The problem is that `COALESCE(SUM(p2.value), 0) as Totalbudget` is getting the `SUM` of the returned(current) line, so there is no difference at all, as we're not getting the sum of all the lines assosiated with a company.

Comment: @Slim - See my edit please, it just a guess. Thats why I need to know some sample data from the two tables to understand how the two tables relates to each other, you will also need to add the where  clause to the `LEFT JOIN` not the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps -

```
SELECT id, company, SUM(NVL(budget, 0)) AS budget
FROM
(
   SELECT id,
   p1.value AS company,
   p2.value AS budget
   FROM  process p
   LEFT JOIN Param p1 on p1.ID = p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Company'
   LEFT JOIN Param p2 ON p2.ID = p.ID AND p2.NAME = 'Budget'
   WHERE TYPE = 'Authorization'
)
WHERE company IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, company
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I got the same result again. :(